# when using app:menu in android's Toolbar I cannot locate the menu items

Tags: android, android-resources, menuitem

I'm trying to use the following xml to inflate my toolbar

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        style="?toolbarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/report_list"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_nav_back"
        app:subtitle="@string/select_create_report"
        app:title="@string/damage_reports" />
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

I can locate the toolbar inside my inflated xml like so:

```
mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
```

and the menu shows correctly

my problem is that since I haven't inflated the toolbar through `onCreateOptionsMenu` I can't use `onOptionsItemSelected` to handle events.

so I decided to add straight listeners to the different menu items.

but the thing is that I can't get a reference to them, when I use

```
 mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.search_reports)
```

it returns null (which frankly I expected) but when I also use

```
mToolbar.menu.findItem(R.id.search_reports)
```

I also get null

however when I inspect mToolbar.actionItems[0] I see that the SearchView's string representation shows that its id is

```
androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView{c1aeba0 VFE...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0800fb app:id/search_reports}
```

and mId from that action item is 2131230971 which translates to 7F0800FB which when searching inside build/generated points to

```
public static final int search_reports=0x7f0800fb;
```

but when I inspect R.id.search_reports instead of 2131230971 (which would make the findMenuItem work) I get -1000038

is there something wrong with the setup of my application? or is there a different way to find a specific menu item

edit: as a side note this seems to work

```
mToolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this::menuItemClicked)

private fun menuItemClicked(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.search_reports -> {
            vm.search_stuff()
            true
        }
        else -> false
    }
```

but I would still like to know why findItem does not work

edit 2: for those that may come upon this, it seems that during evaluation and debugging the resource numbers are indeed different, but if you actually place mToolbar.menu.findItem(R.id.search_reports) in your code and run it , it will work, even though it does not work while debugging

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can set click listener on item like this:

```
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    //remember your menu item id !! mine is R.id.psMenuRefresh

    toolbar.getMenu().findItem(R.id.psMenuRefresh).setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
            Log.i("mytag","helooo");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

There you go.

Comment: that's what I'm saying, that does not work, finditem returns null when called on the menu object of toolbar

Comment: @Cruces are your menu options visible when you run this activity? Im using androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar and this code works just fine

Comment: yes they are, I will try androidx Toolbar, but I don't think that there will be a difference, where did you use your code? I use mine in OnCreate of a fragment

Comment: @Cruces my code is also in OnCreate. I will share you my test project with this code.

Comment: @Cruces https://github.com/urkeke/MyApplication.git check it out

Comment: yeah I figured it out, you seem to be right, the thing is I just checked the resource Id numbers and they didn't match when evaluating with alt+f8 while debugging, but when actually used findItem in the code it worked, modify your answer to write this (in case anyone comes across this in the future and I'll set it as accepted

Answer (score -1):

You need add: onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) and onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) in your activity like this:

The first method it used to inflate menu.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

The second to add listeners:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_share) {
            // YOUR CODE HERE ...
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.action_save) {
            // YOUR CODE HERE ...
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: I know , but as I said I did not wish to do that, because I wish to set up the menu from the xmls